# Enterprise UX Certification

Tags: enterprise

Is there any certification for Enterprise UX out there?
I've been working in Enterprise UX for the last 2 years but I've been wondering if it's out there any certification about it, I've been looking for it in google but I haven't found any specific certification.

Comment: What is Enterprise UX and how it differs form UX? What in your opinion should be in the program of Enterprise UX Certification?

Comment: It's UX applied to big organizations(mainly where UX role is not fully established?) and Enterprise applications. "Enterprise UX is a catch-all term for work done for internal tools—software that's used by employees, not consumers." - https://alistapart.com/article/ux-for-the-enterprise

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Having experience working for big enterprises I think that even in enterprises UX should stay UX and be focused on user even though the are forced to use the software. I think you should look of UX certifications for Managers, not Enterprise UX for Designers. NNGroup training is good for managers. As a designer in enterprise setting you can benefit from Business Analysis and Software Architecture courses. Plus, knowing the culture and what drives decision making in corporations also can help, but I'm not sure if there is certification for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nielsen Norman Group offers various types of certifications. https://www.nngroup.com/training/